# Can others see contents of variables in PHP?

Tags: php, security, variables

This question is as simple as the title states. It's probably been asked  hundreds of times but I couldn't find the answer, so sorry.

Basically, I want to get some information from a  MySQL database from one of the pages on my website and just want to make sure that it is safe to establish the connection on that page because I obviously don't want the information about my MySQL database to be compromised.

I know that anyone can view the HTML source of a webpage with the web browser but I wasn't sure if the same could be done with PHP (variables)...

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unless your server is fundamentally broken and serves up the raw PHP code, the only thing end-users ever will see is the OUTPUT of your script. A properly functioning setup will never serve up PHP code.

If you're worried about the posibility of a leak, then keep sensitive data in a separate file outside of your document root, and `include()` it into PHP. It's no defense against people who have shell access to your server, but it would keep a misconfigured server from leaking that data if the PHP code DOES get served up somehow.

Comment: "Unless your server is fundamentally broken and serves up the raw PHP code" -> liked this line so much.. :) specially the use of word "fundamentally".

Comment: I regret that I have but one +1 to give for this answer

Comment: Ok thank you. I suspected it may be like that but it's reassuring to have it in words. I don't think I'm to worried about 'fundamentally' issues but I may decide to use `include()` anyway when I have more time! How cautious do you think I need to be with a shared hoster?

Comment: @RobAllen Why do you regret it - it is a good answer, isn't it?

Comment: @RobAllen Oh fair enough - your comment just doesn't sound like you meant that personally. I've upvoted it too.